# Kernel of a Second derivative linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

[image]

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me tackle this question.

I have recently been introduced to the idea of a Kernel and have predominantly been looking at it in terms of matrices and not linear maps. So I'm a bit shaky on this area.

However I am aware that the kernel is the set of vectors in the domain of the mapping which are mapped to the zero vector.
Hence I belive it must be the domain of the first derivative here which is mapped to the zero vector.

So my thinking is that the kernel of D_2 should represent any constants given from the first derivative as when derived again these will disappear.

Hence I think the option should be b). But I have no clue whether this is correct or not.

Also could someone explain what the subscripts mean next to the polynomial symbol.

Please can someone help me consolidate this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Find $\ker(D_2)$" is equivalent to "What is the set of all polynomials whose second derivative is always zero?" Perhaps this will help clarify what needs to be checked to obtain the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the set of polynomials that's second derivative is always zero and the ones that have the highest "letter term" being to the power of 1 before deriving. For instance if we were deriving with respect to x then the set that always goes to zero, would be any polynomials that have the highest power of x in the sequence to be x^1. Is this correct?

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused. I get the idea that I'm looking for but could you explain what the subscripts mean next to the polynomials as I don't understand them at all?

Comment: $P(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of all real polynomials. $P_k(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of all real polynomials whose degree is at most $k$. The degree of a polynomial of $x$ is the highest power of $x$ that appears in that polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ be a polynomial then

$p''=\sum_{i=2}^ni(i-1)a_ix^{i-2}=2a_2+6a_3x+...+n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$

$Ker(D_2)=\{p \in P(R):p''=0\}$ $\Rightarrow$  $Ker(D_2)=\{p \in P(R):2a_2+6a_3x+...+n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\}=0$

$2a_2+6a_3x+...+n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_2=a_3=...=a_n=0$ which means

$Ker(D)=\{p \in P(R):p=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\}=P_2(R)$